# xpages document will not ever switch to the edit mode

Tags: xpages

I have tried using the simple action to toggle mode, simple action to change mode to edit, have the view link open the document in edit mode. Nothing actually puts the document fields into an editable state. There are not any authors fields on the document and I have manager access to the database. This is an application update of a classic notes client app to a xpages UI. So I am working with existing documents. I am totally clueless as to what to look at. There are zero errors in the browser or the server console. I can edit the documents just fine in the notes client.

If I create a test application and use the same methods to put documents into edit mode using the above mentioned methods, it works just fine. But not with a xpage using the existing documents. Any guidance you can give me on what to look for would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the "Maximum Internet Access level" of the db?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the ACL and your author fields and the Internet access as Sven suggest